# Delphi arendondamento valores

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Estou com o seguinte problema:

```
                  | Result |
10     / 0,9280 = | 10,77  |
10     / 0,8740 = | 11,44  |
214,35 / 0,9280 = | 230,98 |
```

Obs: Essas informações estão gravadas no servidor com arredondamento, igual o exemplo.

Agora se eu pegar essas informações e inverter para mostrar para o usuário o valor original:

```
                   |  Result   |Correto |
10,77   * 0,9280 = | 9,99456   |  10    |
11,44   * 0,8740 = | 9,99856   |  10    |
230,98  * 0,9280 = | 214,34944 | 214,35 |
```

Como eu consigo fazer esse arredondamento?

Comment: você poderia arredondar com o método RoundTo desta forma, segue exemplo: RoundTo (1.234, -2); //retorna 1.23, então se vc arredondar RoundTo(9,99456, -3) acho que vc consegue o resultado.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver amigo?

Answer (score 1):

Creio que possa utilizar a função [System.Math.SetRoundMode](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Math.SetRoundMode). Segundo a documentação, ele pode assumir **rmNearest, rmDown, rmUp ou rmTruncate**. A documentação traz um exemplo [aqui](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Tokyo/en/SetRoundMode_(Delphi)).

```
SetRoundMode(rmNearest); // Arredonda para o valor mais próximo
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está salvando o resultado com apenas duas casas decimais, evidentemente a posterior multiplicação levará em conta apenas as duas casas e consequentemente não chegará ao valor desejado.
Como exemplo, veja:

Correto:

```
10     / 0,9280 = | 10,77586206896552
```

Seu código

```
10     / 0,9280 = | 10,77
```

Comment: Sim, mas não sou eu que gravo, essas informações já estão assim no servidor. Estou querendo achar uma forma de pegar esse valor do servidor com apenas duas casas decimais e converter no valor original.

Comment: Não tem como com 100% de garantia... pode tentar arredondar o valor final, ex.: `StrToFloat(FormatFloat('0.00',9.99456))` = 10.  
Mas não é garantido que chegará no valor que vc quer...

Comment: Se verificar o terceiro numero depois da vírgula foi menor que 5, alterar para 5 no caso ficaria:
StrToFloat(FormatFloat('0.00',9.99556)) = 10. Será que dessa forma não daria certo?

Comment: Nesse caso específico sim, mas a questão é que nem sempre deverá arredondar para cima. No seu caso não vejo saída.